# How to put a variable into this string in Python?

Tags: python, variables

Pretty much I have this line of code -

```
Popen(["C:\Users\Johannes\Documents\A Customized JonDoFox Portable Profiles - Beta 2\JonDoFoxPortable1\JonDoFoxPortable.exe", "https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html"], )
```

But I'd need to insert a variable into JonDoFoxPortable(VariableHere) so it would look like something like that -

```
Popen(["C:\Users\Johannes\Documents\A Customized JonDoFox Portable Profiles - Beta 2\JonDoFoxPortable(VariableHere)\JonDoFoxPortable.exe", "https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html"], )
```

Still a beginner but if anybody has any ideas I'd be grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

```
Popen(["C:\Users\Johannes\Documents\A Customized JonDoFox Portable Profiles - Beta 2\JonDoFoxPortable" + variable + "\JonDoFoxPortable.exe", "https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html"], )

Popen(["C:\Users\Johannes\Documents\A Customized JonDoFox Portable Profiles - Beta 2\JonDoFoxPortable%a\JonDoFoxPortable.exe"%variable, "https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html"], )
```

Or what Sukrit Kalra posted

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) function.

```
>>> txt = "MyText{}"
>>> txt.format(2)
'MyText2'
```